# How download file from blob?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need a solution on a page.aspx to download file. In database I have a table 'Messages' with two fields: `fileMessageName` (`System.String`), `fileMessageBytes` (`System.Byte[]`).
I need from bytes get a actual file on a page.

Comment: You haven't really tried anything, have you?

Comment: I try a 'Response' + 'MemoryStream' methods. Interesting can I download file on a wrapper (not code-side page) jn some class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about how to do this in ASPX but you should add a new page for download

1. Get the file bytes
2. Add header entry `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`
3. Write your data to the document

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Martin Risell-Lilja

DownloadController in

```
Function File(id As String) As FileContentResult
    Dim Icat = New WebClient().DownloadData("https://file.blob.core.windows.net/app/" + id)
    Return New FileContentResult(Icat, "application/octet-stream") With {.FileDownloadName = "Höbölö"}
End Function
```

For MemoryStream

```
    Function File(id As String) As FileStreamResult
        Dim Icat = New WebClient().DownloadData("https://file.blob.core.windows.net/app/" + id)
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(Icat)
        Return File(ms, "application/octet-stream","Höbölö")
    End Function
```

Get : www.mysite.com/Download/File/bidi.exe

If you wish to authorize User Meta tag  or can slow download custom options.